# Update table with subquery works on mysql but error on oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, subquery

I have table named `TABLE_A` looks like this :

```
ID    DATA    VALUE     LM
---------------------------------
1      7        9       NULL
2     10        5       NULL
3      4        7       NULL
```

This is not actually my table, i use this to shorten my question.
Now I want to update `table_a` with subquery.
This is my query :

```
UPDATE TABLE_A,
(SELECT VALUE AS VAL FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID = 2) AS TEMP
SET TABLE_A.LM = TABLE_A.VALUE + TEMP.VAL
WHERE TABLE_A.ID = 1
```

This query works on `Mysql` but in `oracle` I got error :

```
[Err] ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
```

**EDIT :**

This is my table [SDM_ABSENSI] :

```
PERIODE   TGL_IN       TGL_OUT          IN      OUT      LM     TL
------------------------------------------------------------------
20141011  11/01/2014   11/01/2014    08:00    17:00     NULL  NULL
20141012  12/01/2014   13/01/2014    22:00    07:30     NULL  NULL
20141013  13/01/2014   13/01/2014    08:00    17:00     NULL  NULL
```

My query :

```
UPDATE SDM_ABSENSI A
    (
    SELECT PERIODE, TGL_IN, TGL_OUT, IN, OUT,
        TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TGL_IN,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||IN,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') AS MASUK,
        TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TGL_OUT,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||OUT,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') AS KELUAR
    FROM SDM_ABSENSI
    WHERE SUBSTR(PERIODE,0,6) = '201410'
    )ABSEN
SET A.LM = (24*60) * (ABSEN.KELUAR - ABSEN.MASUK),
    A.TL = CASE WHEN (24*60) * (ABSEN.KELUAR - ABSEN.MASUK) < 0
           THEN 0 ELSE (24*60) * (ABSEN.KELUAR - ABSEN.MASUK)
           END
WHERE SUBSTR(A.PERIODE,0,6) = '201410'
AND A.PERIODE = ABSEN.PERIODE
```

And i got error :

```
[Err] ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
```

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are trying to achieve here. what happens when subquery returns more than one row on what basis you will use `temp.val` column

Comment: @NoDisplayName I updated my question. This not actually my real table.. That query works on mysql, what i need is how to achieve the same result on oracle?

Comment: So you will get only one record from subquery

Comment: @NoDisplayName I updated my question, that was my real problem. I have much column like LM, TL, CP, etc to update, that's why i use subquery. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support `Update from Join` Syntax. Instead you can use `Merge`. Try this.

```
MERGE
INTO    SDM_ABSENSI 
USING   (
        SELECT PERIODE, TGL_IN, TGL_OUT, IN, OUT,
               TO_DATE(To_char(TGL_IN,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||IN,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') AS MASUK,
               TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TGL_OUT,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||OUT,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') AS KELUAR
           FROM SDM_ABSENSI
           WHERE SUBSTR(PERIODE,0,6) = '201410'
        ) ABSEN
ON      SDM_ABSENSI.PERIODE = ABSEN.PERIODE 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET    SDM_ABSENSI.LM = ( 24 * 60 ) * ( ABSEN.KELUAR - ABSEN.MASUK ),
       SDM_ABSENSI.TL = CASE
                WHEN ( 24 * 60 ) * ( ABSEN.KELUAR - ABSEN.MASUK ) < 0 THEN 0
                ELSE ( 24 * 60 ) * ( ABSEN.KELUAR - ABSEN.MASUK )
              END
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. I'm new in oracle and didn't know that Oracle doesn't support `Update From Join` so thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can write such a subquery in Oracle. You should maybe checkout the update statement as its defined in the oracle documentation, here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm

Having said that, what do you really want to do here? What value and under which conditions do you want to assign to the column LM?

That query doesn't look so good, in my opinion. You're trying to build a temporary table from the data stored in table_a and update that same table_a with values from that temporal table... but how? With the maximum of the temporal table? With the value of the same register when the condition is met?

I don't see how that query could work in MySQL either to be honest.

To sum up, could you provide additional info?

[EDIT] Just saw the modification in the question. You can remove the subquery from where it is and place it in the where statement...

UPDATE TABLE_A
SET TABLE_A.LM = TABLE_A.VALUE + (SELECT VALUE AS VAL FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID = 2)
WHERE TABLE_A.ID = 1

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Alberto. But that query really works on mysql. I don't know why didn't work on oracle. So how do i get the same result with oracle? pls help..